# Vuex How to bind store to KendoUi-Vue Grid in transport read

Tags: vuex, kendo-ui-vue

I am trying to bind the data on Kendo UI with the data from Vuex getters.

I have tried the following but no luck. Please help whether where i am missing something on the vuex or on the kendo.

**Kendo Extensions:**

```
<kendo-grid :data-source="kendoDataSource">
</kendo-grid>
```

Components:

```
  computed: {
    customers() {
      return this.$store.getters.customers;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      kendoDataSource: {
        schema: {
          data: function(response) {
            return response;
          },
          model: {
            id: "CustomerID",
            fields: {
              CompanyName: { type: "string" },
            }
          }
        },
        transport: {
          read: function(options) {
            options.success(this.customers);
          }
        }
      }    
     };
```

I am getting the error. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

When i tried to debug the `this.customers` in the transport of kendo the object `this.customers` is always null.

The data are in the format as shown in below:

```
[
    {
      "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
      "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste"
    },
    {
      "CustomerID": "ANATR",
      "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados"
    }
]
```

**Store.js**

```
export default {
  state: {
    customers: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(customers))
  },
  getters: {
    customers(state) {
      return state.customers;
    }
  }
};
```

When i try to bind the data directly on  `options.success(this.customers);`

Like the way shown below the grid get populated with the data successfully. But while i tried to bind using the `getters` there is the error.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
  options.success([
        {
          "CustomerID": "ALFKI",
          "CompanyName": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        },
        {
          "CustomerID": "ANATR",
          "CompanyName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use computed properties instead of data.

```
computed: {
    customers() {
      return this.$store.getters.customers;
    },
    kendoDataSource() {
      const customers = this.customers
      return {
        schema: {
          data: function(response) {
            return response;
          },
          model: {
            id: "CustomerID",
            fields: {
              CompanyName: { type: "string" },
            }
          }
        },
        transport: {
          read: function(options) {
            options.success(customers);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh! you are right. Totally solved. Thank you. But why one question why i can not use getters in data?

Comment: As I understand, when your `getters` change, data will not be change. You need to directly assign `this. kendoDataSource = ...` to make component reactive. In this case, the best practice is using `computed` property